# How to test returning of inputStream with Junit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have the method, that should returns InputStream.

```
public InputStream getInputStream(String path) throws IOException {
...
return inputStream;
}
```

how can i test it with JUnit?

Comment: assertNotNull? What do you want to do with said `InputStream`?

Comment: What's in it? What should be in it? Surely you can consume it and verify that its contents are correct? Or that it's not `null`? Or that it `==` some `mock` you set earlier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An input stream is just an object, so you'd test it in the same manner as you would test any method that returns an object:

Should it be null?
Is it null?
Is the object in the correct state?

The last point is the most important one and will depend on the nature of your stream/application.  It might be sufficient to just test whether the stream has any available bytes (since this will indicate that your path points to a valid resource).  It's down to you to decide how rigorous this test is though.